# How to affect the different directions in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got an image in canvas. I need to scale my image to the top, to the bottom, to the left and to the right differently.

Function `drawImage` has only width and height parameters, but not top, bottom, right and left.

```
drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height)
```

How can I do this?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/GpdLOx) sandbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the image, you just have to calculate the position according to its size.

`ctx.drawImage(img, c.width - img.width/2, c.height - img.height/2,c.width/2, c.height/2);`

In the example above, the image is aligned to bottom right corner.  Btw, I divided it by 2, so you can clearly see the alignment.